# Integrate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp (a t^3 + b t^2 + c t) \mathrm{d}t,\;\;(a,c)\in\mathbb{I}, \; \; \Re(b)\le0$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, complex-numbers

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp (a t^3 + b t^2 + c t) \mathrm{d}t,\;\;(a,c)\in\mathbb{I}, \; \; \Re(b)\le0$$

i.e. an oscillation with frequency $3\Im(a)t^2 + 2\Im(b)t + \Im(c)$ and phase $0$, multiplied by a gaussian window $\exp(\Re(b)t^2)$

Does this even have an analytic form? What sort of methods might help evaluate it?

---

In the case $b=0,\;\Im(a)>0$, defining $p = \Im(a)$ and $q = \Im(c)$:

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(i(p t^3 + q t)) \mathrm{d}t = 
2\int_0^\infty \cos(p t^3 + q t) \mathrm{d}t$$

define $t^\prime = (3p)^{-\frac{1}{3}}t \implies \mathrm{d}t^\prime = (3p)^{-\frac{1}{3}} \mathrm{d t}$

$$\begin{align}
I =& \;2 \int_0^\infty \cos(p ((3p)^{-\frac{1}{3}}t)^3 + q (3p)^{-\frac{1}{3}}t) \mathrm{d}t^\prime \\
=& \;2(3p)^{-\frac{1}{3}} \int_0^\infty \cos(\frac{1}{3}t^3 + q (3p)^{-\frac{1}{3}}t) \mathrm{d}t\\
=& \;2\pi(3p)^{-\frac{1}{3}} \mathrm{Ai}((3p)^{-\frac{1}{3}} q)
\end{align}$$

where $\mathrm{Ai}$ is the Airy function.

I don't mind the $\Im(a)>0$ constraint, but I really need the whole $b$ domain.

---

given $A=\exp(\frac{2 b^3}{27 a^2} - \frac{bc}{3a})$, $T = t + \frac{b}{3a}$ and $\xi = \Im(\frac{b}{3a}) = \frac{-\Re(b)}{3 \Im(a)}$
$$
I = A \int_{-\infty + i \xi}^{\infty + i \xi} \exp(a T^3 + (c - \frac{b^2}{3a})\;T\:)\; \mathrm{d}T
$$

but my complex analysis skills are too weak to get me past there... Also, $\Re(\frac{b^2}{3a}) \ne 0$ so I don't think it converges.

Comment: "If b=0 then you have the Airy function" Well, no.

Comment: Do you mean "no, you don't get the Airy function" or "no, it doesn't have an analytic form"?

Comment: If b=0 then one does not have the Airy function.

Comment: See my edits above

Comment: Two things: if b=0 then the integral is *related* to the Airy function, not the Airy function; please use @.

Comment: @Did hopefully it's clearer / more correct now.

Comment: Given a cubic $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, you can always obtain the [depressed cubic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Reduction_to_a_depressed_cubic) $X^3+pX+q$ where $X=x-x_0$ for appropriate $x_0$. And such changes of variables don't affect the bounds of integration...

Comment: @Semiclassical seeing as X and p would both be complex (seeing as b is complex), does that actually help in evaluating the integral? Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Well, the virtue is that you're back to the $b=0$ case. The only complication is the integration contour; I'd assumed (like in the Gaussian case) that the shift of the integration contour off the real axis isn't problematic. But that may have been too hasty.

Comment: @Semiclassical I've shown as far as that takes me, which isn't very far. Mostly down to my lack of complex analysis skills though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to note that the [depressed cubic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Reduction_to_a_depressed_cubic) approach is only suitable when $\dfrac{b}{3a}\in\mathbb{R}$ , i.e. $b\in\mathbb{I}$

For general $b$ , we can use the ODE approach:

Let $I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{at^3+bt^2+ct}~dt$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dI}{dc}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty te^{at^3+bt^2+ct}~dt$

$\dfrac{d^2I}{dc^2}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty t^2e^{at^3+bt^2+ct}~dt$

$\therefore3a\dfrac{d^2I}{dc^2}+2b\dfrac{dI}{dc}+cI=\int_{-\infty}^\infty(3at^2+2bt+c)e^{at^3+bt^2+ct}~dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{at^3+bt^2+ct}~d(at^3+bt^2+ct)=[e^{at^3+bt^2+ct}]_{-\infty}^\infty=0$

This belongs to the ODE of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0204.pdf, which still can get the general solution in terms of the Airy function.

Comment: Thanks :)

What exactly would be meant by $\;\xi^\frac{3}{2}$, considering that $\xi$ is complex in this instance? $\left(z^3\right)^\frac{1}{2} \ne \left(z^\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$ in the general case (it's ok if $\Re\{z\} > 0$)

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, is the solution valid for the whole Riemann surface or only for the principle value?